# How to send a pdf file from <input> with post request in ionic

Tags: typescript, post, request, ionic3

PDF should be uploaded to the server, i'm trying

```
add(): void {
if (this.st == 1) return
if (this.name == "") return;
console.log(this.fil)
//
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/', this.fil).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  },error => {
    console.log(error.status);
  });
}
```

But request is empty

Comment: What is `this.fill` ?

Comment: Use FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject for file uploading

Comment: fil is the file from input `<ion-input type="file" accept=".pdf" [(ngModel)]="fil"></ion-input>`